# Multiple actions on, or non-transformative use of, reactor types

Tags: java, spring, reactor

I am trying to get my head around Spring Boot and Reactors (having been away from Java for almost two decades). The resource I am learning from gives too-basic examples, and no search is returning any meaningful information: only convoluted documentation that doesn't answer anything.

What I am trying to achieve is - at least in principle - very simple.

I have a function to delete an image stored within `UPLOAD_ROOT`. On upload, the image had a `name` and was assigned an `id`. That image was then stored as `image.id + "-" + image.name`, (allowing upload of multiple images with the same source filename). The `Image` class provides the association of the `id` and `name` values, with that being stored in MongoDB.

The database `Image` is accessed through `public interface ImageRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository <Image, String>`.

Deletion is by `id`. My code at the moment (derived from a version that deleted by filename, and didn't cope with name conflicts):

```
public Mono<Void> deleteImage(String fileId) {
    return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
        imageRepository.findById(fileId)
                .map(image -> {
                    Mono<Void> deleteFile = Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                        try {
                            Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(UPLOAD_ROOT, image.getId() + "-" + image.getName()));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    });
                    Mono<Void> deleteRecord = Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                        imageRepository.delete(image);
                    });
                    return Mono.when(deleteFile, deleteRecord).then();
                });
    }).then();
}
```

The problem is that, wrapped inside the `imageRepository.findById(fileId).map(image -> { ... });`, deleteFile and deleteRecord never happen. Nor the `Mono.when()`.

The other approach, which makes more sense to me, would be to use an alternate function to `.map` that is non-transformative, operating on the supplied `Mono<Image>`'s elements and returning the same `Mono<Image>` so that more could be done with it. But I can't find any reference to anything that enables this.

How do I get all the nested functions to actually happen? (I have tried various things with `.then()` and `.subscribe()` on the end of each, but nothing gave consisten and fully-functional results.) Or is there some secret function that will allow me to perform a non-transformative chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with the use of `Mono.fromRunnable`. 
Try this code:

```
public Mono<Void> deleteImage(String fileId) {
  return imageRepository.findById(fileId)
           .flatMap(image -> Mono.when(deleteFile(image), deleteRecord(image)).then());
}

private Mono<Void> deleteRecord(Image image) {
  return imageRepository.delete(image);
}

private Mono<Void> deleteFile(Image image) {
  return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
    try {
      Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(UPLOAD_ROOT, image.getId() + "-" + image.getName()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Such an obvious approach when put that way.